# How Can I write AddHandler in .htaccess?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, security

I Want to add the `AddHandler` to run php code for .jpg files, 
when I added this `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .jpg` in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf` it worked Fine, but when I add it to `/path/.htaccess` it does not work
Can you explain where the problem is?

Comment: Is .htaccess use enabled on that server with `AllowOverride All` in the vhost?

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the online manual [`AddHandler`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler), there are two entries

- [`Context`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) describes where the directive is allowed. When you see `.htaccess` in the list, you may use it in .htaccess files.
- [`Override`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Override) describes the prerequisite for `.htaccess`. For `AddHandler`, you must have [`AllowOverride FileInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) or `AllowOverride All` activated.